# How can I track uploaded file names through my network using squid?

Tags: squid

I want to track the uploaded file names from my network using squid. For my network I want to monitor the uploads happening and also I want to generate a report of files that were uploaded from my network.

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar problem at sourcebits...
this is how we found a way around...

1. Clear OS Foundation firewall & squid setup
2. jusniffer to sniff the http packets which are going thru port 80
3. Modified the jusniffer and wrote a few ruby scripts to make sure that it is not logging the passwords / usernames / other confidential information. For our requirements, we just wanted to have the uploaded file names..
4. Finally one more script which will analyze the log and generate a report !!!

hope it helps ;)